print statement in python scripts invoked through systemd .service
I have a script which needs to run at startup using ExecStart=/bin/python3 /home/pi/Blink.py.
Blink.py blinks an LED at 1sec intervals, but needs also to print some characters to a terminal screen using the print() statement.
When run from a terminal, this script works correctly, but when invoked from systemd, blinking works correctly, but no characters are visible since no terminal is open at that point in time. The system proceeds to the Ubuntu Mate Desktop and waits there.
How can I open a terminal in the .service file and then continue to invoke the python script in that terminal?

Does this really need to run as a service before logging in to the desktop as a specific user? If so, it needs jumping through some hoops, otherwise it should be as simple as starting a terminal instance running the script upon logging in to the desktop: https://askubuntu.com/a/1383146/380067

(Can't test this, but using the answer linked above, something like mate-terminal -e 'python3 /home/pi/Blink.py')

So your Blink.py apparently prints the characters to its standard output. By default, the standard output of any processes started as services usually goes to the systemd journal.
When a program is started from any interactive shell without redirection, that program will inherit its standard output device from the shell, usually causing the standard output to the terminal used by the shell.
The system services are designed to be independent of user login sessions, and so they normally should not attempt to open X11 GUI windows. The system service might well get started up before the GUI is started up, and if a GUI login screen is used, the X11 server is reset when transitioning from the login screen to user session and vice versa, killing any existing windows. This makes it awkward to access the GUI directly from system services.
(One common solution is to have a separate GUI front-end process running within the user's session, using D-Bus or some other means to communicate with the system service part that might run as a dedicated user account, or even as root if necessary. This is what e.g. NetworkManager does.)
But there are some terminals you could easily use with a system service: any otherwise unused serial ports and virtual consoles.
For example, you could add these lines to your service file:
StandardOutput=tty
TTyPath=/dev/tty9

This would send the output from your service to the 9th virtual console, accessible with Ctrl+Alt+F9 key combination. To return to GUI session, you would then use another Ctrl+Alt+function key combination; the exact function key to use depends on distribution and how it's configured.
Alternatively, you could set up your service as an user service as opposed to a system service: i.e. instead of placing your *.service file into /etc/systemd/system/ directory, you would place it into /etc/systemd/user/ (if you want it to be used by all users of the system) or into ~/.config/systemd/user/ (if you want it used by just a particular user only).
Unlike system services, user services can have access to the GUI session they're started with. Then you could have your service start both the terminal and your Blink.py, by adding lines like this to the service definition:
[Unit]
PartOf=graphical-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mate-terminal -e 'python3 /home/pi/Blink.py'

The PartOf=graphical-session.target ensures the service won't be started until the GUI session is properly set up, and e.g. the DISPLAY environment variable is set. It also tells systemd to shut down your service if the GUI session ends for any reason.
The ExecStart line tells systemd to start mate-terminal, and the options to mate-terminal tell it to start your application, so it will start within the terminal. When started in this way, the terminal window will normally close immediately when your application ends.

The TTY thing is a nice trick! OP said the other method didn't work for them though. What could be missing? I'm following up as I've never tried spawning stuff inside of a GUI session from a service, and I'm interested in learning.

The suggestion to use the /dev/tty9 method seems to work perfectly for me. To return back to the GUI I did CTRL+Alt+F7. Thanks.
Incidentally the idea to use mate-terminal did not work for me but this may have been due to the fact that my .service file was kept in the
/etc/systemd/system

directory.
For example, you could add these lines to your service file:

StandardOutput=tty
TTyPath=/dev/tty9

This would send the output from your service to the 9th virtual console, accessible with Ctrl+Alt+F9 key combination. To return to GUI session, you would then use another Ctrl+Alt+function key combination; the exact function key to use depends on distribution and how it's configured.


If telcoM's answer helped, please accept it by clicking on the grey check mark below their answer's score, to let other people know that their answer worked for you and to  grant them some reputation for the effort of writing it down; also, note that unless you're answering your own question, which doesn't appear to be the case, you shouldn't be answering your own question; if you need more explanation, please leave a comment under telcoM's answer instead.
